# What is the difference between ‘silviculture’ and ‘forestry’?

Tags: word-choice, differences

What is the difference in usage? What associations does the former word trigger that the latter does not (and vice versa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NOAD reports that *silviculture* means *the growing and cultivation of trees*, while *forestry* means *the science or practice of planting, managing, and caring for forests*.
If I say I am a silviculturist, I don't mean I plant forests.

The other grammatical difference between the words is that there are two derivates of *silviculture* (*silvicultural*, *silviculturist*), but there aren't derivates of *forestry* with similar meaning.

Comment: Speaking about equivalents, could *forester* (AHD: “One who is trained in forestry”) and *forestal* (OED: “Of or pertaining to a forest”) possibly be used?

Comment: _Forestal_ (which strangely is not reported in the NOAD) and _forestation_ are derivates of _forest_, not _forestry_. I updated the answer to reflect what I really meant.

Comment: Would it perhaps be helpful and accurate to mention a tree farm as a place where one would practice "silviculture" but not "forestry", or to suggest that someone who cares for animals or plants other than trees in a forest might be practicing "forestry" but not "silviculture"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference would be that *silviculture* applies to any tree, while *forestry* only to the ones in a forest.

Comment: Except that M-W defines *silviculture* as "a branch of forestry dealing with the development and care of forests" and Wiktionary has it as "The care and development of forests in order to obtain a product or provide a benefit; forestry." And indeed the root *silvi* comes from the Latin for *forest*, not *tree*.

Comment: @Martha: That should be an answer, the one I want to click up on!

Comment: Also, AHD defines it as “The care and cultivation of forest trees; forestry,” RHUWD defines it as “the cultivation of forest trees; forestry,” the OED has it as “The cultivation of woods or forests; the growing and tending of trees as a department of forestry,” Wikipedia as “the practice of controlling the establishment, growth, composition, health, and quality of forests,” and Chamber's as “Forestry.” Which is why I am at a loss. There seems to be no clear consensus between all the dictionaries.

Comment: @Orbling: fully answering this question would require researching the contexts where each word is used, and I don't presently have time for that.

Comment: Where I checked (the Dashboard Dictionary on a Mac), silviculture was described as meaning "the growing and cultivation of trees" and silva as wood. I do remember silva meaning forest, but I was misled by the dictionary. I apologize!

Comment: @Martha: Shame, miss your input.

Answer (score 0):

"Silviculture" to me, never having heard it before, just sounds like it's pretentious.  Like a 'Garbage removal expert'.

I admit I'm outside my specialism, though, so there may be some distinction in the field. And I know people who are irritated by people calling themselves 'software engineers' when in reality they're just 'programmers' putting on airs...

Comment: There are *a lot* of questions on Programmers.SE about the whole SE vs Programmers argument.  I would say there is a difference, but a small one.

Comment: Absolutely, and I have my own idea of what the difference is.  My point is that whether there's a distinction between the two phrases, and what that distinction is, is sometimes a subjective one - and that sounds like it might also be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Silviculture involve on field not science ie a farmer can involve on Silviculture  but forestry is science related to forest ie M.Sc. in forestry

Answer (score 0):

Afforestation is the planting of trees in a barren land to increase forest area while silviculture deals with the growth,establishment, development, care and regeneration of stand (plant)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please consider adding references to your answer. For example, cite a dictionary entry, or quote a paragraph where this is used in context.